# Window Planter Box

Tags: screws, drill, brick, masonry, drill-bit

I want to start this off by saying I’m a beginner, so if something is obvious, I’m sorry but I’m just learning. Anyways, I have a 4 foot long by 1 foot deep by 1 foot tall window planter box. My first question is about building out a lower support. My brick house has protruding window ledges and I want the window box to sit closer to the window. The depth of the ledge is 3 1/4 inches. How do a create a support that is level with the ledges? What size (s) of wood should I be using?

My next question is about using a hammer drill. What size drill bit do I need? And taking into consideration the support and brick, what size screws will I need to hang the planter?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then revise to ask just one question per post. Also take the [tour].

Comment: We'll need to see the boxes and ledges or have a much better description. Details matter with something like this if you don't want it to look like a hack job.

Comment: Wood attached to brick in the weather (and planter-box-watering runoff) rots. I'd suggest considering stainless steel or galvanized and painted steel brackets for support as opposed to wood.

Comment: Please add photos of your window (press Edit above and use the editor tools to add photos).   Make sure it's clear what the issue is with the window ledge.  Normally you would use [planter brackets](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=window+planter+brackets&form=HDRSC3&first=1) that give you good control of the height and depth of the planter, so it's not obvious what the problem is with your window.